# git push with url using JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using JGit library to push my changes to the repository. However, I want to provide the URL as well in the push command. I want the equivalent of following command in JGit:

```
git push <url>
```

Is this possible with JGit?

Note: Changing the config file is not desirable. Want to set the URL everytime I push.

Answer (score 1):

`PushCommand::setRemote` also allows setting the remote URL. From the JavaDoc:

> The remote (**uri or name**) used for the push operation. If no remote is set, the default value of `Constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_NAME` will be used.

For example:

```java
push.setRemote( "http://examle.org/repo.git" ).call();
```

will push new commits on the current branch to a branch of the same name on the remote repository.

Comment: I tried this earlier. Actually I want to provide the authentication itself in the url. If I do git push "https://username:password@<url>"  through cmd, it doesn't asks for authentication. But If I am doing push.setRemote( "https://username:password@<url>" ).call(); in java, It is asking for authentication. It should behave same as in cmd, isn't it?

Comment: AFAIK JGit supports the `username:password` scheme. How does the rest of the URL look like? How do you recognize that JGit is _asking for authentication_?

Comment: JGIT is throwing exception : [git.GitUtilities : perfromPull()] - Exception : org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://git.web/repo.git/repo.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered. However I am providing the username and password in the URL itself (push.setRemote( "username:password@https://git.web/repo.git").call())

Comment: What happens if you set a CredentialsProvider?